# Methods for finding the minimal polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

The only methods I know for determining the minimal polynomial of a matrix involve first calculating its characteristic polynomial, then either testing all possible factors or looking at the generalised eigenspaces as you would for Jordan normal form.

Are there any other good algorithmic methods for calculating it? Ideally, I don't what anything involving row/column operations since I don't know my matrix explicitly, but can determine certain properties like its characteristic polynomial.

I would also be happy if you can give me any methods for calculating other properties of the minimal polynomial like its degree.

**EDIT:** For clarification, my matrix comes from a group action and is defined over a finite field, so I could also determine the order potentially, but this may be quite computationally intensive.

Comment: "I don't what anything involving row/column operations since I don't know my matrix explicitly..." What properties do you know?

Comment: One possibility is to start with a vector $v_1 \neq 0$. Then form $v_1, Av_1, A^2 v_1, \dots$ until you reach a linear dependency. This linear dependency has the form $p_1(A) v_1 = 0$ for some polynomial $p_1$. Now, choose a second vector $v_2$ with $p_1 (A) v_2 \neq 0$ (if there is no such vector, you are done). As above, obtain a polynomial $q_2$ with $q_2 (A) v_2 = 0$. Let $p_2$ be the least common multiple of $p_1, q_2$ and continue. Finally, you will reach $p_n (A) = 0$. Then $p_n$ will be the minimal polynomial. I don't know however, if you can do this with your available information.

Comment: @TrialAndError Currently, just the characteristic polynomial (so trace and determinant etc) but I am looking for a method that works intrinsically so without caring about the actual numbers itself hence any and all methods like that will do.

Comment: @PhoemueX: One may as well look for linear dependence among powers $I,A,A^2,\ldots $ of the matrix.

Comment: @hardmath: Yes, but the other method is usually less computationally intensive.

Comment: @hardmath I only wanted answers from a linear algebra viewpoint and to this extent, I believe PhoemueX's answer is most suitable. For more clarification, this arises from studying galois representations of elliptic curves where there are techniques to determine the trace and determinant (and so the characterstic polynomial as it is $2\times 2$). However, I'm still interested in other methods as the size of the matrix will grow when I move to abelian varieties.

Comment: So, does it make sense in your setting to form a matrix-vector product?  Do we have, at least implicitly, a way of defining a basis from which vectors can be formed?

Comment: @hardmath the matrix belongs to the automorphism group of a vector space, and there is a way of choosing a basis to directly determine its action on that basis but my concern is that this then involves the discrete logarithm problem which is far from ideal.

Comment: Your matrix is $2\times 2$? Then why did you not say so right away? Certainly computing the characteristic polynomial would be good enough in this case, as it equals the minimal polynomial unless your action is scalar multiplication (and I hope you can detect _that_).

Comment: Hmm. The Schoof-Elkies-Atkin algorithm used in calculating the order of an elliptic curve does something like this for the Frobenius (acting on $\ell$-torsion). It is not easy. IIRC the original Schoof version just bruteforced the characteristic polynomial, Atkin added an attempt to find eigenvalues, and Elkies added modular curves. And it is the state of the art. I don't know to what extent stuff like it generalizes to abelian varieties (and automorphisms other than Frobenius). But this comparison may indicate that you are asking quite a lot!

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen that's what I have for this case, but as I mention above, I want something that works efficiently for larger matrices which is why I did not mention it originally.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've looked at Schoof's algorithm, but I'll look at what Elkies and Atkin did as well so thanks for that. :)